# What Kinds of Errors Could Cause Alignment to be Ignored?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, arm, alignment

My raytracer is crashing because of a misaligned SIMD NEON operand.  I explicitly aligned it, but somehow it is not correctly aligned at runtime.  The relevant code looks exactly as follows.  When run, it prints, impossibly, `0x7ea3c838`, which is 8-byte aligned, not 16-byte aligned.

```
Spectrum get_spectrum(Vec3 const& rgb) {
    //...
    static_assert(sizeof(Spectrum)==16,"Implementation error!");
    static_assert(alignof(Spectrum)==16,"Implementation error!");
    Spectrum result;
    printf("%p\n",&result);
    getchar();
    //...
    return result;
}
```

I tried to reproduce the error in a smaller example, but **I was not able to**.  This makes me think that the error is some weird memory corruption issue.  Valgrind was unhelpful; its only output was many errors in `libarmmem.so` from the constructor `std::string::string(char const*)`, and then a crash due to [an endian-swapping optimization](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=60166) (which isn't a bug, but just lack of support).

Since I cannot reproduce it elsewhere, I do not expect a neat solution.  What I *am* looking for is an explanation of the kinds of problems that might lead to this behavior.  Tips about what to try to narrow it down would be welcome too.

---

[**Update:** I recompiled all code using `libasan`, a GCC/Clang error-checking compiler builtin.  The bus error still occurs.]

[**Update:** I recompiled all code with Clang.  The program works perfectly.  Hmmmm.]

Answer (score 0):

This might be compiler problem: if it guarantees stack alignment 8 on function entry and do not detect more strictly aligned data to do stack realign in prologue as needed, thing s will be as you described. The fact that error is hardly reproducible makes this probability higher. Your static_assert do not work, because it check implied alignment of data object (which is correct), not real stack alignment on function entry.

You definitely can not do anything here if you are not compiler developer -- even manual inline assembler will go after prologue expansion and stack slots assignment.

The only thing, I can recommend as workaround -- make variable static or global.